# python venv version is different than it is created for

Tags: python-venv

I created python venv for version 3.8 but venv show shows version 3.11. why? How to fix it? i tried to install/reinstall virtual environment that didn't help. uninstall version 3.11 but system installed by itself and I am never able to run venv on python 3.8 version.

```
> python -V
Python 3.8.18

> python3.8 -m venv venv

> source venv/bin/activate
> 
> 
> python -V
Python 3.11.5
```

I tried to install/reinstall virtual environment that didn't help. uninstall version 3.11 but system installed by itself and I am never able to run venv on python 3.8 version.